# Remove outer box-shadow and keeping only inset shadow

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to remove all the outer shadows of all elements but keep the inset shadows. If I do `$('*').css({'box-shadow':'none'});` then it will remove all box-shadows, both inset and outer. How can I keep all inner shadows?

Answer (score 0):

You should change your shadow to inset instead, but you will have to know what the previous values where, something rough like this may work:

```
var prevShadow = $('#myDiv').css('box-shadow');
$('#myDiv').css('box-shadow', prevShadow + ' inset');
```

Comment: How does that work? I have box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px red, 0px 0px 10px blue; and I want to keep only the blue??

Answer (score 0):

Just make the outer color transparent

```
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px red, 0px 0px 10px transparent
```

Or just assign a class to the element(s) with `!important`

```
<div class="something"></div>

.something {
    box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 10px red !important;
}
```

Or just re-do the box shadow all together

```
$('.changeBoxShadow').click(function (e) {
     $('.hasBoth').css('box-shadow', 'inset 0px 0px 10px red');
});

<div class="hasBoth"></div>
<p> <a class="changeBoxShadow">Change Box Shadow</a></p>
```

[Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/85xya958/1)

Comment: I think he wants to not hard code the values elsewhere, so if he decides to change them, he changes it in one place in css and doesn't have to worry about the js or any other css classes.

Comment: he's got JS selector though

Comment: But the selector is $('*'), it's all selectors